# Language: lang-none adds unwanted line breaks

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting, internet-explorer-8, language-hints

The `<!-- language: lang-none -->` hint seems to add unwanted line break after each line.

Without the hint:

```
code line;
another line;
more;
lines;
```

With the hint:

```
code line;
another line;
more;
lines;
```

Using IE8.

[image: Screent shot]

Comment: I'm not seeing it in Chrome and I don't have IE8 handy. Mind posting a screenshot?

Comment: @AnnaLear Done. Also, when the page loads, the lines are condensed as they should be, and only after a second they expand.

Comment: @AnnaLear `<br>`s are inserted after each code line in the second code block. I believe this happens after page load.

Comment: Out of interest, why would one use `lang-none` and not `<pre>...</pre>`?

Comment: @eggyal I like to keep it semantically correct, so try to use `lang-none` for languages that have no prettify support and `<pre>` for things like tables.

Answer (score 8):

As you noted, Prettify is inserting two `<br>` elements in between each line in IE 8 (and IE 9's compatibility mode).

In Firefox 12 and Chrome 19, it inserts only one. IE9 appears to also work (outside the IE8 compatibility mode).

You should probably report this [to the authors of Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/list).

Comment: Okay... I have. Let's see if it helps ;)

Comment: If you reproduced, it might be wise to tag the question accordingly

Comment: Hmm, yeah... I kinda should tag this status-deferred, since can't really do anything about it unless prettify is fixed.

Comment: It would appear it doesn't happen anymore, at least not in this question. Did you update prettify?

Comment: At *least* once, @GSerg.

Comment: Yes, fixed here and [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14224497/11683). `[status-completed]` I guess.

Comment: Ok - marked as such.